# Tangent circles become non-tangent using LaTeX arrowheads

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Please consider this LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->,thick] ({sqrt(2)},{sqrt(2)+2}) arc (45:225:2);
  \draw[->,thick] ({-sqrt(2)},{-sqrt(2)+2}) arc (225:405:2);
  \draw[->,thick] ({sqrt(2)+4},{sqrt(2)+2}) arc (45:225:2);
  \draw[->,thick] ({-sqrt(2)+4},{-sqrt(2)+2}) arc (225:405:2);
\end{tikzpicture}\par
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-LaTeX,thick] ({sqrt(2)},{sqrt(2)+2}) arc (45:225:2);
  \draw[-LaTeX,thick] ({-sqrt(2)},{-sqrt(2)+2}) arc (225:405:2);
  \draw[-LaTeX,thick] ({sqrt(2)+4},{sqrt(2)+2}) arc (45:225:2);
  \draw[-LaTeX,thick] ({-sqrt(2)+4},{-sqrt(2)+2}) arc (225:405:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It should draw two pairs of tangent circles with arrows. Actually, each circle consists of two half-circles with an arrow at the end.

What I get is this:

[image]

As you can see, the circles from the second pair are not tangent. However, both pairs were created by the same process. The only difference is that the second pair uses LaTeX arrowheads, whereas the first pair doesn't.

Is this a known problem? How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you load the `bending` library this works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->,thick] ({sqrt(2)},{sqrt(2)+2}) arc (45:225:2);
  \draw[->,thick] ({-sqrt(2)},{-sqrt(2)+2}) arc (225:405:2);
  \draw[->,thick] ({sqrt(2)+4},{sqrt(2)+2}) arc (45:225:2);
  \draw[->,thick] ({-sqrt(2)+4},{-sqrt(2)+2}) arc (225:405:2);
\end{tikzpicture}\par
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-LaTeX,thick] ({sqrt(2)},{sqrt(2)+2}) arc (45:225:2);
  \draw[-LaTeX,thick] ({-sqrt(2)},{-sqrt(2)+2}) arc (225:405:2);
  \draw[-LaTeX,thick] ({sqrt(2)+4},{sqrt(2)+2}) arc (45:225:2);
  \draw[-LaTeX,thick] ({-sqrt(2)+4},{-sqrt(2)+2}) arc (225:405:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not even know that that library existed! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, you could have used the `decorations.markings` library instead of all those calculations.
[image: decorated circles]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{arrowedcircle/.style={
                    postaction=decorate,
                    decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=between positions 0.125 and 1 step 0.5 with \arrow{latex}
                    }}}
        \draw[arrowedcircle] (0,0) circle (2cm);    
        \draw[arrowedcircle] (4,0) circle (2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to learn as much as I can about TikZ.

Comment: Everyone always has something to learn, hence the beauty of this website.

Answer (score 2):

Just checking with [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.4]
\tzcircle[-->--=.125](0,0)(2)
\tzcircle[draw=none,-->--=.625](0,0)(2)
\tzcircle(4,0)(2)
\foreach \apos in {.125,.25,...,1}
{
  \settzmidarrow{Latex}[red,scale=1.5]
  \tzcircle[draw=none,-->--=\apos](4,0)(2)
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```